# How to parallelize data that is written to h5 file?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, mpi4py

I am very new to `h5py/mpi4py`. I am trying to write some data to a single .h5 file in such a way that 2 processes are being in if `rank == 0` positive test data(positive dataset) values will be written and if `rank == 1` negative test data(negative dataset) values will be written. But when I try to run with

```
mpiexec -n 2 python parallel_exec.py
```

I'm getting

> IOError: Unable to create file (unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable').

Could anyone help me out with this

```
    from mpi4py import MPI
    import h5py

    rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank
    f = h5py.File('parallel.hdf5', 'w')
    f.create_dataset('face_val', (num_pos_imgs + num_neg_imgs, 1), np.int)
    f.create_dataset('eye_val', (num_pos_imgs + num_neg_imgs, 2), np.float32)

    hdf5_index = 0
    if rank == 0:
      for i in enumerate(negative_images):
        f['face_val'][hdf5_index, ...] = 0
        f['eye_val'][hdf5_index, ...] = (magick_number, magick_number)
        hdf5_index += 1
    elif rank == 1:
      for i in enumerate(positive_images):
        f['face_val'][hdf5_index, ...] = 1
        f['eye_val'][hdf5_index, ...] = (magick_number_positive, magick_number_positive)
        hdf5_index += 1
```

Expected:

*Run parallel hdf5 in 2 processes and output a resultant .hdf5 file*

Got:

> IOError: Unable to create file (unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable')

Comment: This is addressed in the h5py documentation. It states HDF5 must be built with the `--enable-parallel --enable-shared` options. Also, h5py has to be compiled in “MPI mode”. Finally, when you Open the file with h5py, you need the `driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD` arguments.Get the details here: [h5py Docs » Parallel HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html)

Comment: @kcw78 I have built HDF5 with those options as stated in http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html and tried that example program also. The example program worked fine but I wanted to implement the same in my code.

Comment: Did you add the mpi arguments to your `h5py.File()` function call:  `driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD`? (as shown in the h5py example)